# Create a php script for installation

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

How can I create a **PHP** script for installing **apache2**?
I'd like to also see the installed version after completion.

Here's what I tried:

```
<?php  
if (!empty($_GET['act'])) {  
    $output = shell_exec ('apt install nodejs');  
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
} else {  
    //$output = shell_exec('nodejs -v');  
    //echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
    ?> 
    <form action="script.php" method="get">  
        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">  
        <input type="submit" value="check version">  
    </form>  
    ?php
}  
?>
```

Comment: PHP would need `root` or `sudo` for this (the install bit) to begin to work, which is definitely not recommended.

Comment: +1 to the above. If your application requires node then you should add it to the list of requirements in your documentation.

Comment: This script is for a project: after i login to remote server as a root user i want to click button to install what i need: php , apache, nodejs!

Comment: How do you want to serve markup rendered through PHP if Apache is not installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to throw light on multiple issues your script has. First of all, you have lots of syntax errors in your script.

**1:** For Instance, You haven't closed `else` part of your condition using `}`. So, Your browser will show something like `localhost is currently unable to handle this request.`.

**2:** Now comes the other thing, Last 3 lines of your script are completely un-necessary, it won't cause errors but it will show up in output which may alter the way you think what error is.

**3:** You are not getting output because you don't have `2>&1` at the end of your command. Once you add it at the end of your command, you will start getting permission error just like this.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Now, this error means that you don't have enough permissions to run the command to install something on your machine. There are multiple ways you can solve this permission issue. If you are running your script as `www-data`, Add the user to `sudo` group using the following command.

```
usermod -aG sudo www-data
```

Once you add the user to the group, you can run commands with `sudo` and you can run this script perfectly. Here is how the final script should like after solving the permission issues first.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['act'])) {  
$output = shell_exec('sudo apt install nodejs 2>&1');  
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
} else {  
$output = shell_exec('nodejs -v');  
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
}

?> 
<form action="so1.php" method="get">  
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">  
<input type="submit" value="check version">  
</form>
```

So, this is how you can make your script execute commands to install packages. Let me know if you have more questions regarding this.

**UPDATE:** I know executing a script with `sudo` is "Harmful" and "Not recommended". But It's a way to make this script work. **And,** If you want to install a package that is bigger in size, add `-y` flag at the end of your command just after `nodejs` to make pre-select the choice to install or not-install a package.

Comment: You've forgotten about all the security issues you open while granting `sudo` permissions to the user running the webserver

Comment: @NicoHaase I know sudo comes with security issues on automation. But man wants to execute a script to install a package. Do you have better idea to install a package without executing a command with `sudo` and without being a root user?

Comment: Yes, I have a better idea: don't do that. The example package to be installed (apache2) already shows that this won't work from the beginning - how to execute PHP through a webserver if none is installed?

Comment: Just think about the following: which process serves the markup generated by PHP if Apache is not installed yet?

Comment: Yeah that's dumb. I totally missed that. I thought he just wanted to install nodejs on a server having apache and php already installed. I read it afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: First , i would thank you for your reply. But when i click the button the packages doesn't work and i receive this error [[Tue Feb 12 15:10:17 2019] 127.0.0.1:56290 [404]: /so1.php?act=run - No such file or directory]

Comment: apache is an example, i want to install nodejs , angular, rails .........

Comment: @AymenKmar, To run the script on php, You must have PHP and if you are executing the script via web browser, you must have Apache installed. In short, you must have apache and php installed in order to run this script via web browser.

Comment: i think my description of my problem doesn't clear. my objectif is to create scripts for install package like nodejs and mysql .... for a remote server . when i run this script the package will i install without put the commande in terminal! @p01ymath if you have some tutorial or codes that's will help me and thanks a lot

Comment: @AymenKmar I have made a whole remote server management system based on PHP. Check out my profile. All you need is to use SSH2 library in PHP. You can perform these tasks on remote server from your server.